# Permission denied when running make_imagenet_mean.sh

Tags: caffe

I'm making an ImageNet with my own data which I have successfully made into two database files in the caffe root directory under folders "DB_train" and "DB_verify".

My `make_imagenet_mean.sh` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Compute the mean image from the imagenet training lmdb
# N.B. this is available in data/ilsvrc12

EXAMPLE=/home/andrew/caffe/DB_train
DATA=/home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12
TOOLS=/home/andrew/caffe/build/tools

/home/andrew/caffe/build/tools/compute_image_mean /home/andrew/caffe/DB_train \
  /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto

echo "Done."
```

When I run the command:

```
andrew@ubuntu:~/caffe$ sudo ./examples/imagenet/make_imagenet_mean.sh
```

I get the error:

```
./examples/imagenet/make_imagenet_mean.sh: 11: ./examples/imagenet/make_imagenet_mean.sh: data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto: Permission denied
Done.
```

Any reason as to why this is happening?

When I run

```
GLOG_minloglevel=0 GLOG_logtostderr=1 /home/andrew/caffe/build/tools/compute_image_mean /home/andrew/caffe/DB_train /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto
```

I get

> ```
> I0215 01:42:17.412768 11659 db_lmdb.cpp:38] Opened lmdb /home/andrew/caffe/DB_train
> I0215 01:42:17.414031 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:68] Starting Iteration
> I0215 01:42:17.660877 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:99] Processed 400 files.
> I0215 01:42:17.661558 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:106] Write to /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto
> I0215 01:42:17.666162 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:112] Number of channels: 3
> I0215 01:42:17.666352 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:117] mean_value channel [0]:132.566
> I0215 01:42:17.666553 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:117] mean_value channel [1]:150.438
> I0215 01:42:17.666694 11659 compute_image_mean.cpp:117] mean_value channel [2]:154.507
> ```

Comment: what are the permissions on `/home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12` folder? try `ls -ltrhd /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12` to see the permissions.

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 2 andrew andrew 4.0K Feb 14 22:26 /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12

Comment: can you run the script without the `sudo`?

Comment: yeah, it returns the same error.

Comment: is it possible `/home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto` already exists? if so try renaming it. I suppose the script does not support overwriting.

Comment: hm when i move it out of the folder it returns `data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto: not found`

Comment: try `GLOG_minloglevel=0 GLOG_logtostderr=1 /home/andrew/caffe/build/tools/compute_image_mean /home/andrew/caffe/DB_train /home/andrew/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto` Do you see any log output on screen before the error message?

Comment: it seems like you have an extra space after the line break `'\'` character in your `make_imagenet_mean.sh` script. If you ran the command directly, it seems to execute just fine ;)

Comment: two hours of frustration and a few minutes of exhilaration... ;)